# Visual Studio 2012 Color Theme on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, vssettings

Actually I'm working with both versions and I love the Dark Style of VS2012.

I know there is a lot of plugins for VS2010 that make it like VS2012, such icons, IDE color and so on.

I'm refering to the color theme ".vssettings" file format, I've being looking another posts and I cannot found any related to this.

Anyone knows?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Import the following style from here

http://studiostyl.es/schemes/c-dark-scheme-for-use-with-expression-dark-theme

Comment: That's not exactly same colors, right? I'm not sure if you got the point, on VS2012 go to Tools>Options>Color Theme>Dark
This is the styling that I'm refering.

Thanks anyway :-)